# Interpretation of the adjective "outstanding"

Tags: meaning-in-context, ambiguity

In my holidays I met a woman who is originally from Australia. She told me she lived in many places due to her husband's work and also traveled much around the world. Although she's already seen many places, she added that there are still a lot of places she'd really love to go to. I asked her:

> Which places are outstanding?

What I actually intended to ask is which places she want to visit but she answered that question regarding which places she considers as most amazing.

I was aware of the other meaning of *outstanding* but I didn't expected she to perceive the question that way since the previous sentence of her was about "she hasn't seen everything yet".

Probably the sentence had been more clear if I'd say "still outstanding" but I now wonder if the usage of *outstanding* regarding "not yet done" is less common that people tend to interpret it as "excellent" if reasonable in context (which indeed is in this context).

Furthermore, is it perhaps an unusual collocation of *outstanding* and *places* regarding "not yet done". Considering examples of OALD and M-W Learner's Dictionary, they are limited to "unpaid" and "still existing problems". "Not yet visited places" are neither problems nor money issues.

---

I don't use [australian-english](/questions/tagged/australian-english) as I don't want to restrict this question to one particular area. I don't believe there's a specific interpretation of this word peculiar to Australian English. For that reason, opinions from British and American people are also appreciated.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: Still outstanding could be interpreted as "still excellent" since some places have been ruined by war or too many tourists :) _Which places are on the top of your list to visit_ would be less ambiguous in my opinion, but still could be soliciting her opinion on places she would recommend, now I read it twice

Comment: That reminds me of the joke about the tourist who wanted to meet a farmer outstanding in his field. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you think about the word *outstanding* itself, you'd notice how it generally means "unique in a group of similar objects or people (*stands out*, get it?).

It thus can **both** refer to something that is not-yet-done (while it's supposed to be, because the *group* that it belongs to has mostly done stuff), but it can also refer to a certain positive quality of uniqueness.

For me, however, the common idiom seems to be to usually use *outstanding* to mean *astonishing, great, impressive, unique,* unless followed by something that explicitly implies a task-based logic:

> This is **outstanding** work, Harry Potter! (*surely means 'great work', not 'work to be done'*).
>
> I'll make a list of some **outstanding** tasks. (*one can argue that the speaker has great tasks to do, but he/she probably meant not-yet-done*).

In the end, it's all about context. In your question:

> What are some outstanding places?

it seems a bit awkward to assume either interpretation. I would've said:

> What are some places you're planning to visit?

Or:

> What are some places you haven't yet been to?

Or even:

> What places are on top of your list?

But this is going outside the scope of your question.

Comment: 'What places are on top of your list?' isn't exactly unambiguous itself.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The OP was having a casual conversation; the question makes sense in context.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth “She added that there are still a lot of places she'd really love to go to” is what precedes the question.

Comment: "tasks outstanding" would be clearer in your example. I am not sure if it is grammatically correct, though.